# Postgres: difference between DEFAULT in CREATE TABLE and ALTER TABLE in database dump

Tags: postgresql, default, pg-dump, database-sequence

In database dump created with `pg_dump`, some tables have `DEFAULT`s in the `CREATE TABLE` statement, i.e.:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  f1 integer DEFAULT nextval('test_f1_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL
);
```

But others have an additional `ALTER` statement:

```
ALTER TABLE ONLY test2 ALTER COLUMN f1 SET DEFAULT nextval('test2_f1_seq'::regclass);
```

What is the reason of this? All sequential fields were created with type `SERIAL`, but in the dump they look different, and I can't guess any rule for this.

Comment: any differences in whether or not these were set to primary keys?

Comment: If some tables are used as FKs and some are not, that might be a difference.. creating the indexes after loading the data may be what it's trying to do for efficiency's sake

Answer (score 0):

The difference must be that in the first case, the sequence is “owned” by the table column.

You can specify this dependency using the `OWNED BY` clause when you create a sequence. A sequence that is owned by a column will automatically be dropped when the column is.

If a sequence is implicitly created by using `serial`, it will be owned by the column.